# Post form to other controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have one HomeController that is for landing page (home,about,contact us) and in home view I have registration of two types(2 separate viewmodels) and login (another viewmodel).I would like to know if there is a way to post form from index view ( HomeController ) to another controller.I'm trying to do this with tag helpers, but it seems it doesn't work. Here`s my code where i'm trying to do this

```
<form asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Register" method="post" role="form" class="ui large form">
....
</form>
```

And here is my Register action in Employee controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(EmployeeRegisterViewModel employeeRegisterModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IdentityResult result = await _service.CreateEmployeeAccount(employeeRegisterModel);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(EmployeeController.Index), "Employee");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(employeeRegisterModel);
    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Try  `@using (Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller",FormMethod.Post)){...}`

Comment: change your asp-action to asp-action="Register/Register"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the razor syntax `Html.BeginForm`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "ui large form"}))
{

}
```

[image]

Or in plain HTML do this

```
<form action="/ControllerName/ActionName" asp-action="Register" method="post" role="form" class="ui large form">
....
</form>
```

Comment: Old comment but you cannot have an action attribute and an asp-action attribute (for the latter example).

Answer (score 2):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "YourController", FormMethod.Post, null))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Html PsBk Click" />
    }
```